# When using Core Location, how should a choice between CLBeacon (iBeacon) and CLLocation (Coordinates) be made?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-location

Basically I need to choose a way to get and compare user locations. I am familiar in general with getting coordinates via CLLocation/CLLocationCoordinate2D, but I think using iBeacon would be better in it is possible.

To determine if iBeacon/CLBeacon is possible for my task, I have a few questions about it: 1) Can an iPhone send out a iBeacon signal to other phones while the applicable application is closed? (2) Is iBeacon much more accurate for precise indoor location determinations? (3) Are there any other limitations that Apple set to using a phone as an iBeacon. (4) How precise in feet are coordinates, particularly for indoors at a large location like a conference center.

Answer (score 0):

This is an iBeacon:

[https://www.amazon.com/iBeacon-Bluetooth-Energy-Proximity-Device/dp/B00JEGXITG](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00JEGXITG)

Do you have one of those in your store, your house, your museum or other public space? If you do, your users can communicate with them (“You are approaching Noname’s house”.

But somehow I don’t think you have one. So perhaps it would be better to stay with CLLocation.

But if you do have one, as in some large museum or other public space that has placed them, then you can help the user know for example what room this is. Accuracy of distance is not what they are about: see [CLBeacon: How can I get the distance from the IBeacons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035600/clbeacon-how-can-i-get-the-distance-from-the-ibeacons) for example.

Here is more about using a phone as a beacon: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/turning_an_ios_device_into_an_ibeacon_device

Comment: Don't have one. The idea was to have all users of an application turn their phones into beacons and get their locations that way.